# Can 'corrplot' package in R be used to construct a correlation matrix for binary and continuous variables?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I am working with multiple binary and continuous variables and want to determine potential correlations between them. I have tried using the 'corrplot' package in R to compute a correlation matrix describing such relationships but keep getting the following error "Error in cor(Zamcor) : 'x' must be numeric]".

The code is the following (with a sample data frame):

```
# Create the variables
PriceHa <- c(25,60,30,9)
Ecoregion1 <- c('1','0','0','1')
GMA <- c('1','0','0','1')
FarmSize <- c(30,40,50,60)
Area <- c(1,0.5,3,4)

#Make the data frame
Zamcor <- data.frame(PriceHa, Ecoregion1, GMA, FarmSize, Area)

# Group correlation test 
corr.test(Zamcor)

# Simple visualisation of correlation analysis effect size including significance    
x <- cor(Zamcor)
cor(x,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
colnames (x) <- c("Price/ha", "Ecoregion 1","GMA", "Farm size", "Area")
rownames(x) <- c("Price/ha", "Ecoregion 1", "GMA", "Farm size", "Area")
p.mat <- cor.mtest(Zamcor, conf.level = .95)
p.mat <- cor.mtest(Zamcor)$p
corrplot(x, p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = .05)
```

I have been advised about using [point-biserial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) as this can handle both binary and continuous variables. However, it appears there is [no advantage to using that over the corr.test function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226157/p-value-for-point-biserial-correlation-in-r). But when I use corr.test it doesn't work "Error in cor(x, use = use, method = method) : 'x' must be numeric".

My question - which function would be most suitable to use for my binary and categorical variables that will still enable me to plot a correlation matrix and not violate the assumptions of the correlation test?

Comment: show code and some data using `dput`. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: This question is more a [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) question rather than a SO question, being a theorical question and not a code question.

Comment: I re-formulated the question as I got no response on CV. Any help would be much appreciated!